# Simple HH:mm:DD clock in HTML5 WITHOUT JavaScript

Tags: html, counter, clock

is possible write counting clock only using HTML5?
Or maybe only counter +1/each second.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is it something like this? http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: can HTML5 make a time machine too? Of course not, it's not almighty. Use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be frickin cool, but neither HTML5 nor CSS3 have the capacity to do this.

You need to use a real programming language (PHP/JS/Python...). 
Markup-Languages(like HTML or CSS) only work declarative.

Comment: It is possible. See the second answer by @mark-lloyd

Answer (score 4):

I have just written a 12-hour digital clock that uses NO JavaScript. Maybe it wasn't possible when this was first posted, but it definitively is now.

http://notstupid.us/clox/dclock.html

I wrote that on the current Firefox and also tested on the latest Chromium as well as Internet Explorer 11 and Chromium Edge beta. There's currently no way to set it (it always starts at 12:00:00) but I should be able to add that some time (probably using server-side script).

The code is all in one file (with inline CSS).

April 7 2021: I now have a way to set the clock. http://notstupid.us/clox/dclock.php adds a small server-side script to change the animation statements so the clock starts at the current time (US Central time).

Comment: Please convert to countdown timer (inverse timing) :-) And also post the source code for PHP version.